# Issue with the my work Okta domain (mywork.okta.com) and openconnect VPN

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn

Since version 14 (and now 18.04), when connecting on my job cisco VPN (with openConnect), I always struggle to have the local domains working correctly.

Wen wire connected from my job, everything is working just fine. However, when connected from my home (with wifi), it is a nigthmare.

The workaround given was to add "Additional search domains". And this work partially.

My first issue was with git, the domain git.myworkaws.io, was not resolved. Adding this one to the "Additional search domains" worked just fine.

However, my nightmare is with okta. I have the domain mywork.okta.com which work just fine without the VPN (and which I think it is not much local). However, right after I'm connected to the VPN, I'm no more able to connect to this domain.

The nightmare comes with the fact that okta is the SSO, therefore without this one working I cannot log to any other application of m job.

By the way, this problem never occur with my phone samsung, neither under windows, neither with my apple tablet. Therefore, would it be possible to manage DNS and local domains like other devices so we do not have to struggle that much with all this?

Emotion aside, does anymore encounter the same problem as me with okta under ubuntu?

I validate the problem with Chromiun and firefox

Cromiun version:
Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)
Firefox:
63.0 (64-bit)

Ubuntu version:
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

Comment: Note that one workaround that works often is to clear the dns cache with `sudo systemd-resolve --status`

Comment: Finally, today I thing I found the real workaround. Before connecting to vpn, I sign in to okta trought mywork.okta.com (make sure to do all the login process), then I connect to the vpn and just then the vpn is able to access mywork.okta.com. Note that I had also flush ubuntu dns and chronium DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the problem was related to the mtu. The command below solved the problem.

```
sudo ifconfig vpn0 mtu 1300 up
```